# Getting "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set" while trying to run jar file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, x11, putty, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a jar file through Putty, which is uploaded via Amazon Web Server. I've tried to change the compiler compliance level from 1.8 to 1.7. I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
        at Smiley.<init>(Smiley.java:10)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

[I've enabled X11 forwarding in Putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW6e9.png)

The jar file works fine, when I run it from my desktop.

Comment: can you try with mobaXTerm client ?

Comment: yes it doesn't work. AWS doesn't have/support X11

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure a few basic X11 packages are installed on your AWS server.  In particular, you'll need the `xauth` and `xhost` programs.  With Amazon Linux, install the `xorg-x11-xauth` and `xorg-x11-server-utils` packages.

Comment: Ensure the `X11Forwarding` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set to `yes`.

Comment: How do I access the sshd_config? Have writing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the terminal